# Calculate the DFT of a signal x[n] given from a set of data in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, dft

I have a set of data, given as a 3142x2 double matrix and I want to calulate the DFT (`X[k] from k=0 to k=N-1`). Column 1 represents time and column 2 represents the number of sunspots.

After calculating the DFT I want to plot the amplitude function `abs(X[k])`.

Here's how I tried to solve it, where *`ssd`* is the dataset:

```
y = fft(ssd(:,2)');
plot(ssd(:,1)',abs(y))
```

Which gives me a graph like:
[image]

I'm pretty sure this is not right, but I don't understand what is wrong.

Here's the file with data if it's any use: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15991564/sunspots.m

Comment: why don't you think it is right?

Comment: is the time steps (first column) equally spaced (i.e., uniform sampling)?

Comment: do you need [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html)?

Comment: @Shai Yes, the time steps are equally spaced

Comment: in that case `fft` should work for you. why are you not satisfied with the plot you got?

Comment: @Shai I was expecting something else but it might be right

Comment: were you expecting the peak to be in the middle?

Comment: BTW you are plotting the Fourier coefficients (Y-axis) as a function of time (X-axis) it makes no sense. The X-axis should be frequencies.

Comment: @Shai How would I go about creating a frequencies-axis?

Comment: @Lightvvind Look at the duplicate.  I did this for an audio file, but it's the same thing for any 1D discrete signal.